# Write to XML file or use MongoDB?

Tags: asp.net, xml, mongodb

I have an web application that allows certain domain objects to be associated with a url.  Right now, if we rollback the production database to our development database (which we do regularly), we have to go into the appropriate table and change the urls to point to their development environment equivalent.  My manager wants a way to have the urls stored in some sort of flat file, so when we rollback the database, we don't have to change any urls.  The production environment would have its own version of the flat file with production urls, while the development environment would have its own version of the flat file with development urls.  The application would just read off the flat file in the current environment.  He also wants the ability for end-users to CRUD these urls in the flat file through the interface.  Right now I am trying to go through the options and see what is best.  It is between reading/writing an xml file or using MongoDB (would be using it here for the first time).

If anyone could give me any advice as to which one would be ideal (or any other suggestions), I would be greatly appreciative!

This is an asp.net 3.5 web application.

Comment: So, this is just a list of URLs? Why won't a simple text file with name value pairs do?

Comment: it is in essence just a list of urls, but with the tasks of having the domain objects having a reference to the url's key (id, etc.), and making sure that the keys are unique, but not unique enough (guids) that there is a very very unlikely chance that the production version of the flat file will have the same ids as the development flat file, and the potential issues of file locking, I wanted to know if there were any better alternatives than just a text file.

Comment: If you cache the file and use the cached version, there will be no IO contention.

Comment: At some point I am going to have to write to the file itself.  Also having it cached doesn't solve my problem of making sure the keys are unique but not unique enough that another version of the file will not have the same keys.... Honestly, I think this flat file requirement from my manager is bonkers...

Comment: Oded, please enter what you said as an answer.  I ended up doing what you suggested - just a plain ole text file.  I would like to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a flat file (key value pairs - one per line).

IO contention can be made to be very low if you cache the file.

Assuming changes are infrequent, you could also write a wrapper around the cache, to invalidate it when it changes and write the changes to disk. This will start to perform poorly the more concurrent changes to the list occur.

Answer (score 0):

An other suggestion :

You could have an action that replace the development url with the production one and store those 2 values in the web.config. I'm doing this for a project and it works fine. I do a backup from my db, restore online, call my update action witch do a loop in all my objects that I want to replace a url and save it back.

Comment: It is not just two urls.  Each domain object could have a completely unique url.  Also, I don't want to have to do something to change the urls after a rollback.  We are doing that now, it is just updating the db.  We want to get rid of that step.

Comment: then you can do it with mongo if you want, it's easy to do when using this : https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo